# Compare a value with all the values in array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am trying to make the following function run but I have stucked badly. I have an object "gidsAll" which I want to compare with each feature: feature.attributes.__gid.

The function is used in Openlayers for styling purpose of the features (points and lines). It is executed for each  "feature.attributes.__gid" and what I want is to simple compare this value with all the values inside the "gidsAll". If the value matches one of the value in "gidsAll" then return green otherwise return red.

I think I need to use a loop somewhere but I can not make it work.

```
    var styleContext = {
            getColor: function (feature) {
            //alert(typeof(feature));//object
       // for (key in gidsAll){
            if (Math.round(feature.attributes.__gid) == Number(gidsAll)){
               return "green";
            } else {
                return "red";
            }   
        //} 
    }                           
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` to loop over all the objects properties.

> `Object.keys` returns all the *enumerable* object's own properties of the object it receives.

```
 var styleContext = {
        getColor: function (feature) {
        var objectKeys = Object.keys(gidsAll);
        for (var i = 0; i < objectKeys.length; i++)
        {
           if (Math.round(feature.attributes.__gid) === parseInt(gidsAll[objectKeys[i]], 10)) 
           {
               return "green";
           }
        }
        return "red"; //nothing has been found
    //} 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked for me! May I ask what is the number 10 you included?

Comment: @dkar The radix, that ensures it's converted into a decimal number.

Comment: I don't see much reason to use `Object.keys` here. A simple `for in`-loop would've worked as well.

Comment: @Bergi `for in` works nicely, find `Object.keys` a safer bet (without inheritance). You never know if some third party library secretly added a property to the `Object.prototype`

Answer (score 2):

You should check all the properties in the object before you return `red`, because you need to make sure there are no `green` matches. Note, that `return "red"` is outside the loop:

```
var styleContext = {
    getColor: function (feature) {

        for (key in gidsAll) {
            if (Math.round(feature.attributes.__gid) == Number(gidsAll)) {
                return "green";
            }
        }

        return "red";
    }
};
```

Comment: @Mouser: Your answer doesn't explain what was wrong with OP's approach and how it should work, that's all I meant. Not that your solution was wrong.

Comment: @Bergi The OP already knew he needed a loop, so I created one and explained what the loop is doing. Basically the same?

Comment: @Mouser: Not as demonstrative as dfsq did, otherwise I wouldn't have missed your explanation of the algorithm :-)

Comment: But *key* isn't kept local and should have a *hasOwnProperty* test. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Just another version using ES5 [*Object.keys*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14) and [*Array.prototype.some*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.17) methods:

```
var styleContext = {
  getColor: function (feature) {
    return Object.keys(gidsAll).some(function (p) {
      return Math.round(feature.attributes.__gid) == gidsAll[p];
    })? 'green' : 'red';
  }
};
```

If you do this a lot, use a loop as it's faster, but *keys* and *some* are concise.